# Convergence of a sequence of suprema of expected values

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, uniform-integrability

Consider a sequence of stochastic processes
$$((X_f^{(n)})_{f \in F})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}.$$
All the random variables $X_f^{(n)}$ are defined on the same probability space and assume only non-negative values. In my case $F$ is a unit ball of some separable Banach space. I am looking for a way to express the condition
\begin{equation}\label{condition}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{f \in F} \mathbb{E}\left[ X_{f}^{(n)}  \right] = 0
\end{equation}
in a fashion similar to ``convergence in probability + uniform integrability = convergence in $L^1$''. It would be  easy if either there was no supremum over $F$ or the supremum was inside of the expectation, but in the above case I cannot really come up with an if-and-only-if condition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the conditions
$$
\tag{1}\lim_{R\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{f\in F}\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)}\mathbf{1}\{X_f^{(n)}>R\}\right]=0
$$
and
$$
\tag{2}\forall \varepsilon >0,\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{f\in F}\mathbb P\left(X_f^{(n)}>\varepsilon\right)=0.
$$
The decomposition
$$
\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)} \right]=\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)}\mathbf{1}\{X_f^{(n)}\leqslant \varepsilon\}\right]+\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)}\mathbf{1}\{\varepsilon <X_f^{(n)}\leqslant R\}\right]+\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)}\mathbf{1}\{X_f^{(n)}>R\}\right]
$$
(valid for $\varepsilon< R$)
gives the bound
$$
\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)} \right]\leqslant   \varepsilon +R\mathbb{P}\left(X_f^{(n)}>\varepsilon\right) +\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)}\mathbf{1}\{X_f^{(n)}>R\}\right].
$$
Consequently, for each $\varepsilon< R$,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{f\in F}\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)} \right]\leqslant   \varepsilon +R\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{f\in F}\mathbb{P}\left(X_f^{(n)}>\varepsilon\right) +\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{f\in F}\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)}\mathbf{1}\{X_f^{(n)}>R\}\right].
$$
By (2), this reduces to
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{f\in F}\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)} \right]\leqslant   \varepsilon   +\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{f\in F}\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)}\mathbf{1}\{X_f^{(n)}>R\}\right].
$$
and by (1), we get that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{f\in F}\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)} \right]\leqslant \varepsilon$, which is sufficient to conclude that $$\tag{3}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{f\in F}\mathbb E\left[X_f^{(n)} \right]=0.$$

Actually, the combination of conditions (1) and(2) is
equivalent to (3), but might be easier to check in the practise.

Comment: May the downvoter care to leave a comment?

Comment: Thank you very much for your exhaustive answer!

Comment: @MarcinWnuk You are welcome!